# Defining environment variables with another variable

Tags: bash

For long and boring reasons, I need to retrieve one environment variable based on the value of another.
e.g.

```
export LOG_PROCESSOR=LOGCOURIER
export LOGCOURIER=/usr/bin/blah
echo  ${$LOG_PROCESSOR}
-bash: ${$LOG_PROCESSOR}: bad substitution
```

How can I get the value `/usr/bin/blah` echo'd in Bash like this?

Answer (score 4):

Of course after finding nothing on google for ages, I find the answer 3 seconds after posting my question.  You do:

```
 > echo ${!LOG_PROCESSOR}
 > /usr/bin/logcourier
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export LOGCOURIER=/usr/bin/blah
export LOG_PROCESSOR=$LOGCOURIER
echo  ${LOG_PROCESSOR}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to indirect parameter expansion, `bash` 4.3 will have named references.

```
declare -n LOG_PROCESSOR=LOGCOURIER
```

After this declaration, a change to one variable results in a change to the other.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Python, this can be done like so:

```bash
export LOG_PROCESSOR=LOGCOURIER
export LOGCOURIER=/usr/bin/blah
echo $(python -c "import os; print(os.environ[os.environ['LOG_PROCESSOR']])")
> /usr/bin/blah
```